# Safari displays my site terribly

Tags: safari, positioning

Im a new developer, and I just finished my first site.  Works fine in all browsers, except safari.

Unfortunately I didn't install a copy of safari while I was developing it, so these issues went unnoticed. I did check every other large browser tho. 
Figuring, if it worked in IE it should work in anything else...

Please open up www.enniya.net in safari, and than in chrome or some other browser to see what I am taking about.

By looking at it I do have a theory.

The background, font, colors, transparencies of divs, border colors, thats all their, but the positioning is destroyed.

But the logo position is correct, so my first theory is that 
90% of the content is positioned with vw and vh 
while the logo actually uses % for positioning...

Except that the latest readings tell me the newest versions of safari understand VH and VW ??? So I dont know.

If you need to see my code let me know, I didn't provide it initialy because Im not really sure what specifically I could provide that would solve this problem.

Comment: I don't see differences... I use safari on OS X and your site works well

Comment: strange I literally just downloaded safari today on win 10 and its completely destroyed... A user told me that the site was not working properly. Thats how I found out. 

Another thing that was strange is when that user reported it to me, he only reported that one part...the tab in the menu that says character creation, which links to an anchor called character test, didnt work. 

Now if he saw what I am seeing, he would have said the whole site is broken. 

and your telling me its fine... 

Now im confused

Comment: Ok I am reading now, that Apple safari for windows support was dropped years ago. I have an old version of Safari running for windows. That explains why its completely broken for me. 

So its possible the user also has an outdated version